# Microsoft SDK Version

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

The error I am getting is here:

```
#if defined( _WIN32 )
    #ifndef WIN32
        #error error // error calls here
    #endif
```

I wrote a program in MS VS2008 that works fine, however when I transfer it over and compile it in MS VS2010, I get a bunch of errors.

Some header files and libraries I include are as follows:

```
#include stdlib.h
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h
#include io.h
#include math.h
#include mmsystem.h
#include iostream

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "odbc32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "odbccp32.lib")
```

Now, I think the problem is this. In VS2008, when I right click on mmsystem.h and say "open containing folder", it points me to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include`

Whereas in in VS2010 when I do this it points me to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include`

1. Could this be the source of the errors, and
2. How could I make VS2010 point me to `v6.0A\Include` rather than `v7.0A\Include`?

Thanks

Comment: What are the errors?  No one can help you unless you articulate precisely what's going on.  Otherwise, you're just saying, "my program won't compile".

Comment: The 6.0 vs 7.0 is just the version of the SDK, VS2010 obviously comes with a newer one. Unless there's a very good reason, you probably shouldn't try to force it to use the old one.

Comment: Thanks for posting the error but I can't see that code in any of the v7.0a headers. Is it in your own code? If so, that means your code is relying on WIN32 (without the underscore) being defined. I guess that's not defined by default anymore. Why not just add it to your project defines, or add that block of code but with a `#define WIN32` not the #error into the top of your precompiled header / project header, or modify your code to use _WIN32 instead?

Comment: Any idea, why you don't use `<>`s in the includes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out finally. In properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions add WIN32

Answer (score 1):

You can change the include folder path for you project in the project properties but most likely the errors are not from the included headers but because in Visual Studio 2010 the C++ compiler has changed to be more strict about certain coding styles which where not considered erroneous before.

In most cases the new compiler, while being more strict, will force you to write better code.

But, to know for sure, can you post the specific compile-time errors you're getting?

Here's a link which also might be useful to you if you're trying to [change the include directories in Visual Studio 2010 when coming from Visual Studio 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx).

Comment: I don't think changing the Microsoft SDK can be changed in the include folder path. My include folder path is currently empty. Also, I am pretty sure this doesn't have to do with coding standards, for example: ` #if defined( _WIN32 )
  #ifndef WIN32
   #error error.
  #endif' is giving me an error, whereas in VS2008 it is not.

Comment: You should look at your Project Properties, under the VC++ Directories tab page. Regarding the error that you say you're getting for the `#if defined`, can you edit the question and post the code sample which give the error?

Comment: The directories will be in your settings as `$(WindowsSdkDir)Include`. But the WindowsSdkDir value is set by the Platform Toolset option - see C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v100\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v100.props (or \Platforms\x64\). I think you really ought to understand and fix your errors though.

Comment: _WIN32 vs WIN32 - did you upgrade the project files from 2008 or did you create new projects? Are you relying on these defines in your code, or just the header files?

Comment: I just added the project files (cpp and h), I didn't upgrade.